# Visit to Poland with UK refugee travel documents

Tags: visas, poland, refugees

I have a UK refugee travel document according to the Geneva Convention 1951.
Can I travel to Poland without visa?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you hold a residence permit, [you do not need a visa](https://www.unhcr.org/uk/about-us/background/4ec262df9/1951-convention-relating-status-refugees-its-1967-protocol.html):

> If you are a holder of British refugees travel document (issued on the basis of the Convention of 28 July 1951) and you hold a residence permit for the UK (in addition to the travel document), you are exempt from the visa requirement.

However, the rules for travel with 1951 documents aren't harmonised across Schengen, so you should check about documentation requirements if you intend to transit through another country.